# C# Sql Connection can not connect to server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, sqlconnection

I'm trying to connect SQL server in my virtual machine with following connection string: `"Server=qqvm;Database=a_test;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=<pass>;Connect Timeout=0"`

Firstly I had 'Network connection' exception with inner 'Access Denied' exception with empty stack trace. I did some digging and enabled 'Named Pipes' in SQL Configuration Manager. 
After that I got this exception:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=11281; handshake=1;

However, I'm still able to connect via SQL Management Studio to that server remotely. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be lots of responses here. https://www.google.com/search?q=Connection+Timeout+Expired.++The+timeout+period+elapsed+while+attempting+to+consume+the+pre-login+handshake+acknowledgement.++This+could+be+because+the+pre-login+handshake+failed+or+the+server+was+unable+to+respond+back+in+time.++The+duration+spent+while+a&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Maybe increase the Connect Timeout in your connection string?

Comment: what is netbios name/ip of server and SQL server instance name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally in my case specifying IP address instead of `qqvm` name solved the problem. Still don't know why, though. It worked a week ago.